# Eigenspaces and subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue for an $n \times n$ matrix $A$, would the associated eigenspace be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It depends on how you define the *eigenspace* of $\lambda$.

Comment: @azif00 is there a sensible definition of eigenspace which is not a subspace?

Comment: @D_S What if the associated eigenspace to $\lambda$ is just the set of all the eigenvectors with eigenvalue $\lambda$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The eigenspace of $\lambda$ is
$$
E_\lambda:=\{v\in \mathbb{R}^n~|~Av=\lambda v\}
$$
Lets check that this is a subspace.  First $0\in E_\lambda$ since $A0=\lambda 0=0$.  Next, if $v_1,v_2\in E_\lambda$ and $r\in \mathbb{R}$, then
$$
A(rv_1)=rAv_1=r(\lambda v_1)=\lambda (rv_1)
$$
and
$$
A(v_1+v_2)=Av_1+Av_2=\lambda v_1+\lambda v_2=\lambda (v_1+v_2).
$$
Hence, $rv_1\in E_\lambda$ and $v_1+v_2\in E_\lambda$ which proves that $E_\lambda$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.